# Jenkins DSL pipeline issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

So I've got this groovy script that supposed to seed my DSL jobs but I am not sure what I am doing wrong when fetching the credentials and assigning them to env vars:

```
for(job in product_base_jobs) {
pipelineJob("${job}") {
    definition{
        cpsScm {
            scm {
                git {
                    branches('staging')
                    remote {
                        credentials('jenkins-git')
                        url("git@gitty.local/${job}.git")
                    }
                }
            }
            scriptPath("./Jenkinsfile")
        }
        triggers {
        }
    }
    wrappers{
        colorizeOutput()
        timestamps()
        credentialsBinding{
            usernamePassword('ARTIFACTORY_USER','ARTIFACTORY_PASS','JenkinsArtifactoryCredentials')
            usernamePassword('ACCESS_KEY','SECRET_KEY','Jenkins_S3')
        }
    }
    environmentVariables{
        env('ARTIFACTORY_USER',"${ARTIFACTORY_USER}")
        env('ARTIFACTORY_PASS',"${ARTIFACTORY_PASS}")
        env('ACCESS_KEY',"${ACCESS_KEY}")
        env('SECRET_KEY',"${SECRET_KEY}")
    }
}
```

}

I also tried to use another approach unsuccessfully:

```
        credentialsBinding{
            usernamePassword{
                usernameVariable('ARTIFACTORY_USER')
                passwordVariable('ARTIFACTORY_PASS')
                credentialsId('JenkinsArtifactoryCredentials')
            }
            usernamePassword{
                usernameVariable('ACCESS_KEY')
                passwordVariable('SECRET_KEY')
                credentialsId('Jenkins_S3')
            }
        }
        environmentVariables{
            env('ARTIFACTORY_USER',"${ARTIFACTORY_USER}")
            env('ARTIFACTORY_PASS',"${ARTIFACTORY_PASS}")
            env('ACCESS_KEY',"${ACCESS_KEY}")
            env('SECRET_KEY',"${SECRET_KEY}")
        }
    }
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Processing DSL script jobs.groovy
Warning: (jobs.groovy, line 30) acceptMergeRequestOnSuccess is deprecated
Warning: (jobs.groovy, line 34) addNoteOnMergeRequest is deprecated
Warning: (jobs.groovy, line 35) addVoteOnMergeRequest is deprecated
Warning: (jobs.groovy, line 36) acceptMergeRequestOnSuccess is deprecated
ERROR: (jobs.groovy, line 50) No such property: ARTIFACTORY_USER for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.toplevel.EnvironmentVariableContext
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there a bug that I am dealing with or is it just a wrong approach. Normally I would use the WitchCredentials as part of a scripted fashion but I want to consolidate a number of jobs that have a lot of similarities in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pipeline job type does not support `wrappers` and `environmentVariables`. It's an issue in Job DSL that these methods are available, see [JENKINS-31832](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31832).

Instead of using Job DSL to add the credentials, use Pipeline code in your `Jenkinsfile` to access any credentials. See [Credentials Binding](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/):

```
node {
  withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mylogin', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
    sh '''
      set +x
      curl -u $USERPASS https://private.server/ > output
    '''
  }
}
```